# Are there drawbacks on Disabling @EnableWebSecurity in Spring Boot for a dedicated Microservice?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, microservices

I have a Spring Boot main application which serves as an MVC app. This application performs some computation which is outsourced into a microservice. The microservice is also a Spring Boot application. Both, main and microservice have Spring Security added.

The main application has to establish a secure connection to the microservice which is done through an API key set in the header. The verification on the microservice side is done via an `OncePerRequestFilter`.

When I don't touch Spring Boot's automatic configuration, the microservice gets configured with all the default `SecurityFilter` I don't really need, such as `SecurityContextHolderFilter`, `LogoutFilter`, `RequestCacheAwareFilter` and many more.

Now here is my question:

What is the best way to disable all the usesless filters I don't need? Is it safe to omit `@EnableWebSecurity` thus telling Spring Boot to not configure any of these, or do I have to be aware of eventual drawbacks?

All tutorials I've found regarding this topic just leave the auto configuration untouched, but imo this is wasting resources since the request never requires one of these filters to be processed. So why set them in place in the first time? The `OncePerRequestFilter` is the only one which has to work reliably.

Many thanks for any information